# how can i return the output of a text

Tags: command-line, text-processing

This is related to a question i asked in overflow, It remains unanswered so i though I'd try asking it in segments

My objective is to return the special \n function, If i were to run

```
echo -e "My name is \nnick rock and i \nlive by the sea shore." > file
```

Then when i cat that file you get something like this

```
My name is
nick rock and i
live by the sea shore.
```

What I'm looking to do is reverse the \n return function, so when i echo the file with something like this

```
echo -aoE '([a-zA-Z]){1,5}' file

output
My 
name 
is
nick 
rock 
and 
i
live 
by 
the 
sea 
shore.
```

I'll get this instead

```
My name is nick rock and i live by the sea shore
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is

```
$ tr  '\n' ' ' < file
My name is  nick rock and i  live by the sea shore.
```

`tr` utility is for translating sets of characters, in this  there's only one character `\n` in SET1 and space in SET2. As for `< file`, that just redirects the file into program's stdin stream.

But if for some reason you need a shell-only way, then this is sufficient:

```
$ while IFS= read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do printf "%s " "$line" ; done < file
My name is  nick rock and i  live by the sea shore.
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this command line, it's an improvement of @Sergiv Kolodyazhnyy which print the `\n` at the right place

```
while IFS= read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do printf "%s " "$line" ; printf "\n" ; done < test.txt
```

(sorry to not be able to comment)

Answer (score 1):

You can also echo unquoted command-substitution:

```
echo $(<infile)
```

Comment: I like this one, but one should be aware that this will replace every sequence of characters in `$IFS` (usually space,newline,tab) by one space character.

Comment: .... which is how [word spliting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html) is happening here

Answer (score 0):

Here are some options:

1. using `awk`, with an unset record separator (aka 'paragraph mode') and the default field separator

   ```
   awk -vRS= '{$1=$1} 1' file
   My name is nick rock and i live by the sea shore.
   ```
2. using `xargs` with no explicit command

   ```
   $ xargs < file
   My name is nick rock and i live by the sea shore.
   ```
3. using `fmt` from GNU coreutils:

   ```
   $ fmt file
   My name is nick rock and i live by the sea shore.
   ```